# Trying to download the CIFAR10 dataset using 'torchvision.datasets' on my computer

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch

i am trying to download the CIFAR10 dataset on my computer using the last two lines of the following code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./Users/Sohrab/Downloads', train=True,
                                    download=True, transform=transform)
```

I execute it in Google Colab,but after that,when i look in my Downloads file on my computer,i do not see
the CIFAR10 dataset.
Is it actually stored on my computer or does Colab store it somewhere else(in a cloud architecture for instance)?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colab` stores the data in running instance's disk. If it resets you have to redownload. You could also save it in your Google Drive but that's some trouble and IMO not worth it for CIFAR10.

Comment: @sosam In StackOverflow we upvote answers instead of saying thanks. Glad I could help though. :)

Comment: i did not know,sorry about that!